# RAM usage increases with grpcio pip package 1.50.0 compared to 1.49.1

Tags: grpc

I have two docker images, one built with grpcio 1.50.0 and the other with 1.49.1. Otherwise they are the same.

We ran these two images on two identical machines, and we see the image with 1.50.0 would use 21.GB more RAM.

Once we downgrade the version from 1.50.0 to 1.49.1, then the two machines will use the same amount of RAM.

Is this known?

Comment: More information is needed: which language for the server/client was used?  What kind of workload are you running?

Comment: This is grpcio, so it's in python. It's a pytorch/xla workload, so it involves Tensorflow XRT and I believe the usages are mainly in XRT.